# Pipeling more than one QtGraphicalEffects effect

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I have an image and I want to apply on top of it two QtGraphicalEffects effects: Blend (multiply mode) and Hue/Saturation. Quoting from the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgraphicaleffects/qtgraphicaleffects-index.html):

> Pipelining multiple effects together is a simple way to create even
>   more impressive output.

```
Item {
    Image {
        id: image1
        source: "image1.png"
        visible: false
        smooth: true
    }

    Image {
        id: image2
        source: "image2.png"
        visible: false
        smooth: true
    }

    Blend {
        id: blendImage
        anchors.fill: image2
        source: image2
        foregroundSource: image1
        mode: "multiply"
        visible: false
    }

    HueSaturation {
        anchors.fill: image1
        source: image2
        saturation: -1.0
    }
}
```

This code doesn't produce the wanted result, it seems that the blend is lost or not even considered for the output of the HueSaturation result. How can I pipe the effects one on top of the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to merge the effects you need to stack them (the source of your second effect must be your first effect).

You just need to change the source of **HueSaturation** to ***blendImage***

```
    HueSaturation {
            anchors.fill: image1
            source: blendImage
            saturation: -1.0
    }
```

Try this:

```
    Item {
        Image {
            id: image1
            source: "image1.png"
            visible: false
            smooth: true
        }

        Image {
            id: image2
            source: "image2.png"
            visible: false
            smooth: true
        }

        Blend {
            id: blendImage
            anchors.fill: image2
            source: image2
            foregroundSource: image1
            mode: "multiply"
            visible: true
        }

        HueSaturation {
            anchors.fill: image1
            source: blendImage
            saturation: -1.0
        }
    }
```